# Add Custom Style to QuickSight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Is it possible to add custom CSS to change the font-size, font-weight? I have been searching through AWS documentation, reference guide, but no success. All I have found is: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/example-modify-visuals.html

Answer (score 0):

With hosted visualization tools, you usually don't have much leeway on how things are presented, since the service provider is also trying to keep a consistent look for their application.

With that said, there's still things you can change like x/y label, chart title font size etc. Quicksight also allows you to define your own custom theme where you can change fonts and colors. You could incorporate this as part of your solution. "Themes" can be found on the left-most panel when viewing a dashboard. Here's an official link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/themes-in-quicksight.html